# Look-like POS keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboards

I'm seeking for a special type of additional keyboard.

Need a pool of 20-30 fully programmable keys on a couple (or more) of 'shifts'. USB connector. Black color.

I searched for POS keyboard and found something like the attached one, but maybe there are more suitable types or models.

Please advise something similar, but **not** gaming keyboard. And the budget is important too, the cheaper one is better.

[image]

Comment: POS = [point of sale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point_of_sale#Noun). [POS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale)